# Formatting the Lengthy Parameters in a better way

Tags: python, formatting

Should I have made a line break `convert_to_quick_mode(` and `from_exported_cdf,`

```
        convert_to_quick_mode(
          from_exported_cdf,
```

code:

```
class QuickModeConverter(object):
    def run(self,
            from_exported_cdf,
            from_exported_msword, 
            to_export_quick_mode_cdf, 
            to_export_quick_mode_msword
            ):

        convert_to_quick_mode(
          from_exported_cdf,
          from_exported_msword, 
          to_export_quick_mode_cdf, 
          to_export_quick_mode_msword
        )
        pass
```

Comment: I suspect that you may have a deeper issue that causes you to have this unusual problem in the first place. Maybe it's a poor abstraction, maybe it's poor naming. Could you provide more context about what your function aims to accomplish, and what its parameters mean?

Comment: Perhaps this is a red herring, but if you're looking to avoiding some typing, `run = staticmethod(convert_to_quick_mode)` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Best option would be to just use `*args` (or `**kwargs` if order does not matter), as follows:

```
class QuickModeConverter(object):
    def run(self, *args):
        convert_to_quick_mode(*args)
```

Comment: but I think make parameters explicitly is more readable for maintaining code, and the order of the params is meaningful in my code :)

Comment: @poc It's a good point if it's a user-facing code. In this case, the way you describe is a correct, at least style-wise.